# Why is ~3 equal to -4 in Python?

Tags: twos-complement

I'm getting started in Python programming. I'm reading a basic tutorial, but this point is not very clear to me. I would appreciate any help you can give me.

Comment: This has nothing to do with pyton but with how negative numbers are represented in binary (see wikipedia/google for 2's complement).

Comment: @skaffman: *This has nothing to do with python*

Comment: @skaffman: title is just fine

Comment: Does every language use the ~ operator? If not, then I don't see why the Python tag is bad.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

~3 means "change all the 1s to 0s and 0s to 1s", so if 3 in binary is 0000000000000011, then ~3 is 1111111111111100.  since the first bit of ~3 is a 1, its a negative number.  to find out which negative number, in 2s comliment, you invert all bits and add 1, so inverted we are back to 3, then added 1 we get 4.

Answer (score 9):

~3 means 'invert' 3. With [two's complement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement) on natural number datatypes, this becomes -4, as the binary representation is inverted (all bits are flipped).

Comment: Just to show it in hex:3 = 0x00000003
~3 = 0xFFFFFFFC and the numbers are signed therefore it is negative.

Answer (score 4):

Because signed integers are usually stored using [two's complement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement), which means that the bitwise inverse of an integer is equal to its algebraic inverse minus one.

Answer (score 0):

It's the invert operator, and returns the bitwise inverse of the number you give it.

Answer (score 0):

It's not just Python, it's the integer numeric representation of almost all modern computers: two's complement. By the definition of two's complement, you get a negative number by complementing the positive number and adding one. In your example, you complemented with `~` but did not add one, so you got the negative of your number minus one.