# why -3==~2 in C#

Tags: c#, .net, conditional-statements, bitwise-operators, twos-complement

Unable to understand. Why output is "equal"

**code:**

```
 if (-3 == ~2)           
    Console.WriteLine("equal");
 else
    Console.WriteLine("not equal");
```

**output:**

```
equal
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why is ~3 equal to -4 in Python?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3916753/why-is-3-equal-to-4-in-python)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How does the bitwise complement (~) operator work?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/791328/how-does-the-bitwise-complement-operator-work)

Answer (score 61, accepted):

Because [two's complement bit-arithmetic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two's_complement) makes it so

Cribbed from the wikipedia page and expanded:

```
Most
Significant
Bit          6  5  4  3  2  1  0   Value
0            0  0  0  0  0  1  1   3
0            0  0  0  0  0  1  0   2
0            0  0  0  0  0  0  1   1 
0            0  0  0  0  0  0  0   0
1            1  1  1  1  1  1  1   -1
1            1  1  1  1  1  1  0   -2
1            1  1  1  1  1  0  1   -3
1            1  1  1  1  1  0  0   -4
```

So you get:

```
0  0  0  0  0  0  1  0  =  2
1  1  1  1  1  1  0  1  = -3
```

And as you can see, all the bits are flipped, which is what the [bitwise NOT operator (`~`)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d2bd4x66(v=vs.71).aspx) does.

Comment: And for those curious about why negative numbers are represented this way, try adding -1 to 1 and see how you arrive at zero :-)

Answer (score 8):

This stackoverflow post explains why:

[What is the tilde (~) in the enum definition?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/387424/what-is-the-tilde-in-a-c-enumeration)

> is the unary one's complement operator -- it flips the bits of its operand.
>   in two's complement arithmetic, ~x == -x-1

Answer (score 3):

It's due to the two's complement representation of signed integers: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Twos_complement

Answer (score 2):

Because it uses two's complement.

Answer (score 0):

There is a big difference between these two operators.

> "The ~ operator performs a bitwise
>   complement operation on its operand,
>   which has the effect of reversing each
>   bit. Bitwise complement operators are
>   predefined for int, uint, long, and
>   ulong."

[msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d2bd4x66%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

The two's complement of 3 is:

1...1101

The (signed) one's complement of 2 is:

1...1101

It's easy to do:

One's complement: Flip the bits.
Two's complement: One's complement + 1.

Why is this useful? Computers can subtract numbers by simply bit flipping and adding.