# int max = ~0; What does it mean?

Tags: c#, bitwise-operators

int max = ~0;

What does it mean?

Comment: Look this `why -3==~2` ( http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4471823/why-3-2-in-c )

Answer (score 8):

The `~` operator is the unary bitwise complement operator which computes the bitwise complement. This means that it reverses all the bits in its argument (0s become 1s and 1s become 0s). Thus,

```
int max = ~0;
```

which is setting `max` to the negation of the 32-bit value `0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000` resulting in `1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111`. As we are storing this result in an `Int32`, this is the same as `-1`.

Whether or not it is better to say

```
int max = ~0;
```

or

```
int max = -1;
```

depends on the context. If the point of `max` is to have a number all of whose bits are `1` I would choose the former. If the point of `max` is to compute the maximum of a list of non-negative integers, I would choose the latter (well, I'd prefer `int max = Int32.MinValue;` and even more so, I'd just prefer `int max = list.Max();`).

Answer (score 5):

The ~ operator is a bit inverse, so ~0 gives you an integer value with all ones (in binary).

Answer (score 5):

It is a bitwise negation of the bytes 0000....0000. It is the value of an integer where all bits are set to 1.

In an unsigned situation it would be the maximum possible value. In a signed situation it is -1.

Answer (score 4):

~ is the complement operator, which flips the bits of the operand. Since zero has no bits set, the complement will have all bits set, which is also the maximum sized integer (assuming unsigned). For signed numbers, you're going to get -1 instead, so calling it "max" is a bit of a misnomer.

Answer (score 3):

Bitwise complement.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d2bd4x66.aspx

A literal 0 (as in the code above) is an int.
An int is a 32 bit binary value. The value 0 has all the bits set to 0.

The ~ operator is a bitwise compliment. i.e. I swaps all the bits.
As all the bits were 0 they are all turned into 1. So we have a 32 bit value
with all the bits set to 1.

C# sharp uses 2 compliment. Which encodes -1 in an int as all bits being 1

```
0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000   == 0

operator ~

1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111   == -1
```

So  =>  `~0 == -1`

Answer (score 3):

~ means bitwise not, it inverts all the bits in the given integer. In a signed int this will give you -1 (since all the bits in the int will be flipped from 0 to 1.) Look up two's complement for more information on this one.

In an unsigned int (uint) this would give you the maximum value of an integer (since the most significant bit in an unsigned int doesn't determine the sign.)

Answer (score 3):

As noted, ~0 yields 0xFFFFFFFF.

However, I suspect the original programmer is confused. executing `int max = ~0 ;` sets the signed integer `max` to the value -1.

Answer (score 0):

As others have stated, ~ is the bitwise negation operator. It will take all bits of the integer value and toggles 0 and 1 (0 -> 1 and 1 -> 0).

~0 equals to -1 for a signed integer or Int32.

Usually either ~0 or -1 is used as the "ALL inclusive" mask (asterisk) when you are implementing a layer-based filtering system of some kind where you use a "layerMask" argument which by default equals to -1 meaning that it will return anything (does not filter). The filter is indeed using a AND operation (valueToFilter & layerMask).

valueToFilter & -1 will always be non-zero if valueToFilter is also non-zero. Zero otherwise.