# = (~0); What does it mean?

Tags: c

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [Is it safe to use -1 to set all bits to true?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/809227/is-it-safe-to-use-1-to-set-all-bits-to-true)
>   [int max = ~0; What does it mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4765201/int-max-0-what-does-it-mean)

Hello,

I have stumbled upon this piece of code..

```
size_t temp;
temp = (~0);
```

Anyone knows what it does?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operators_in_C_and_C%2B%2B#Bitwise_operators

Comment: @Bart: What a *marvelous* website!

Comment: This is an **erroneous** approach to getting the maximum value. You should instead assign it the value `-1`, which is guaranteed to behave properly. See the discussion [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/809227/is-it-safe-to-use-1-to-set-all-bits-to-true). (Effectively a duplicate, considering the amount of information in the linked question.)

Comment: @GManNickG But size_t is unsigned.

Comment: @Vincent: Did you read the link I provided?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`~` is the bitwise not operator, it inverts each bit of the operand. In this case the operand is 0, so every bit is initially 0, and after applying the bitwise not every bit will be 1. The end result is you get a size_t filled with 1 bits.

Comment: The result is that of converting an `int` filled with 1 bits to `size_t`. With two's complement, that's a `size_t` filled with 1 bits.

Comment: @SteveJessop size_t is an unsigned type

Comment: @Vincent: But `int` is signed, which is why the representation affects the `int` -> `size_t` conversion. If `int` were ones' complement then the result would be `0`, and if `int` were sign-magnitude then the result would be `(size_t)(INT_MAX) + 2`.

Answer (score 2):

That's one way typically used to assign a `size_t` value built of all binary ones independent of actual size of `size_t` type. If that's the purpose of that code one should instead use `(size_t)( -1 )`.

Btw [here's an identical question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4765201).

Comment: I don't think there's `static_cast` in **C**. He did say C.

Comment: I won't -1 because it's a common misconception, but that's incorrect. They are, in fact, different. Assigning `-1` to an unsigned type is guaranteed to result in the largest value that type can hold. Contrarily, assigning `~0` could, on a one's compliment machine, end up with the value zero. There are other pitfalls, too; see the discussion [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/809227/is-it-safe-to-use-1-to-set-all-bits-to-true).

Comment: ok cool thanks !
SO did not find the similar one.. neither did I. Sorry !

Comment: @GMan: out of curiosity: are there *any* one's compliment machines in active use out there?

Comment: @GMan: Thank you, I couldn't find that question. I'll edit the answer.

Comment: @Joachim: Probably in some esoteric facility somewhere, who knows.

Comment: @Joachim: in the many times this has come up on SO, I think someone has named a 1s' complement machine that had a C compiler, some of which are still capable of operating (if not necessarily in active use and not in production). Can't remember what.

Answer (score 2):

sharptooth's answer is correct, but to give you more detail, the `~` is a binary operator for [NOT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operators#NOT). Basically, you're assigning the binary equivalent of `NOT 0` to temp and that will set every bit to 1.

Answer (score 2):

How about this?

C++ code:

```
#include <limits>

std::size_t temp = std::numeric_limits<std::size_t>::max();
```

C code:
Please take a look the [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3472311/what-is-a-portable-method-to-find-the-maximum-value-of-size-t).

I think it is more proper way.