# What is ~ in C#?

Tags: c#, syntax, operators, bitwise-operators, tilde

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the tilde (~) in a C# enumeration?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/387424/what-is-the-tilde-in-a-c-sharp-enumeration)
>   [What does the tilde mean in an expression?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7986978/what-does-the-tilde-mean-in-an-expression)

I have download a CRC code snippet from the internet in C# having these lines:

```
byte[] hashBuffer = UInt32ToBigEndianBytes(~hash);
```

or

```
public static UInt32 Compute(byte[] buffer)
{
   return ~CalculateHash(InitializeTable(DefaultPolynomial), DefaultSeed, buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
}
```

Comment: You will like this Question [why -3 == ~2 in C#?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4471823/why-3-2-in-c)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> The ~ operator performs a bitwise complement operation on its operand, which has the effect of reversing each bit. Bitwise complement operators are predefined for int, uint, long, and ulong.

From: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d2bd4x66.aspx

And although it is not used this way in the example you have shown, the `~` character is *also* used to declare a [destructor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/66x5fx1b.aspx) in C#.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [MSDN: ~ Operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d2bd4x66%28v=VS.80%29.aspx)